# Latest Post Thumbnail Alt Text Missing

Tags: php

Im using the following code on my WordPress custom theme home page to display the latest three portfolio posts:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=portfolio&showposts=3'); ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="portfolio-box">

                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),’thumbnail’ );
                             echo '<img width="100%" src="'.$image_src[0].'" alt="'.$image_alt.'" title="'.$image_title.'">';
                        } else { ?>
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/fallback.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                    <?php } ?>

                   <div class="portfolio-box-caption portfolio-box-caption-blue">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                <!-- <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?> -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name-work">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

However the image alt text isn't appearing the in the final page source. Could someone be kind enough to show me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `$image_alt` and `$image_title`. I don't see where you did it in your code.

You need to change/add like this

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),’thumbnail’ );
      $attachment_meta = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id());
      echo '<img width="100%" src="'.$image_src[0].'" alt="'.$attachment_meta->post_excerpt.'" title="'.$attachment_meta->post_title.'">';
      } else { ?>
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/fallback.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    <?php } ?>
```

Image's 'alt' text is stored as a string in wp_postmeta with the meta_key of '_wp_attachment_image_alt'.

That you can grab like this

```
$img_alt =  get_post_meta($thumb_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
```

**EDIT:**

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),'thumbnail' );
      $attachment_meta = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id());
      $img_alt =  get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
      echo '<img width="100%" src="'.$image_src[0].'" alt="'.$img_alt.'" title="'.$attachment_meta->post_title.'">';
      } else { ?>
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/fallback.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't really do what I want though. Ideally, I'd like the alt text for the image to be included, not the post_excerpt. Same for the tittle, I'd like the actual image title, not the post_title. All of my images in the media repository have alt text and title text so that's what I'd like to display in the source code.

Comment: Each media attachment store it's title in post_title and caption in post_excerpt. The alt is just an example. For the post_title it is the title of the attachment, not the loop post title (for most it will be the filename).try post_content too.

Comment: I edit my answer. Hope you will place it where it must be.

Comment: Where does $img_alt =  get_post_meta($thumb_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); need to be placed?

Comment: Before the echo to be available in it.

Comment: Is it `$img_alt =`  or should it be `$image_alt =` ? Can't get the image alt text and image title text to appear.

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks. Had to tweak is slightly but it now does what I want it to :)

Comment: Cool ! don't forget to mark the question as resolved

Answer (score 0):

`<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),’thumbnail’ );
                            $img_alt =  get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
                            $attachment_meta = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id());
                            echo '<img width="100%" src="'.$image_src[0].'" alt="'.$img_alt.'" title="'.$attachment_meta->post_title.'">';
                         } else { ?>
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/fallback.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                        <?php } ?>`